# SQLAlchemy join syntax using multiple column names

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

This is the following sql query I want to execute and works perfectly on the command line:

`select * from table1 join table2 using (col1, col2)`

I am cannot figure out how to make this execute using SQLAlchemy and any help would be appreciated.

There are no foreign keys between the tables. The table rows can only be paired up by values matching in multiple columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Considering Entity1 maps to table1, and Entity2 maps to table2:

```
rows = session
    .query(Entity1, Entity2)
    .join(Entity2, (Entity1.col1==Entity2.col1) & (Entity1.col2==Entity2.col2))
    .all()
```

`rows` will be a list of tuples where `rows[][0]` is `Entity1` and `rows[][1]` is `Entity2`.
You can use `.join()` and then specify the join condition with the second param. If you omit the join condition, then the `.query()` method alone generates a cross join between table1 and table2.

Comment: And if I wanted to make sure all of the other columns from Entity2 are included after the join, what tweak would I have to make on that command?

Comment: @Anthony Have you tried `session.query(Entity1, Entity2).join(...).all()` ? That will return a list of tuples.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: This seems to do the trick. The list of tuples representing the results of each table wasn't quite what I was imaging the result to be based on what the SQL query returns. This might be why I was having so much trouble figuing it out, but is exactly the data I needed to extract. Thank you!

Comment: The important thing is the `() & ()`. I was trying with `Entity1.col1==Entity2.col1 and Entity1.col2==Entity2.col2` which just didn't give the expected results but also no error :-/