# Sqlalchemy and many to many relationship linking two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bigcommerce

I am having trouble creating a link between the Orders and ProductOrders table with Sqlalchemy.  I need to link order_id, which exists in both Orders table and ProductOrders table in order to query orders from a store and also get the product data as well.  I am working with BigCommerce API so order_id is only unique to each specific store and not unique globally like  Shopify API.

The order_id is the link I wish to create, but it only unique for each store.id in the Store table so I can't do a simple join as the order_id is no unique on its own.  Do I use the Store table to link this many to many relationship, or do I need to use the StoreUser table that is already linking the store_id and user_id together?  I am so confused.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

    storeusers = relationship("StoreUser", backref="user")

class StoreUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

class Store(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_hash = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False, unique=True)
    access_token = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    scope = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)

    admin_storeuser_id = relationship("StoreUser", 
                            primaryjoin="and_(StoreUser.store_id==Store.id, StoreUser.admin==True)")
storeusers = relationship("StoreUser", backref="store")

store_orders_id = relationship("Orders",
                            primaryjoin="(Orders.store_id==Store.id)")
store_orders = relationship("Orders", backref="store", cascade="all, delete")

store_product_orders_id = relationship("ProductOrders",
                            primaryjoin="(ProductOrders.store_id==Store.id)")
store_product_orders = relationship("ProductOrders", backref="store", cascade="all, delete")

class Orders(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

class ProductOrders(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'), nullable=False)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    base_price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need a multi-column primary key, so the unique constraint is `order_id`+`store_id`

This answer shows multi column primary keys in sqlalchemy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036128/210101

And this one shows joining on multiple columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164913/210101